# Pandas : SQL SelfJoin With Date Criteria

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

One query I often do in SQL within a relational database is to join a table back to itself and summarize each row based on records for the same id either backwards or forward in time.

For example, assume table1 as columns 'ID','Date', 'Var1'

In SQL I could sum var1 for the past 3 months for each record like this:

```
Select a.ID, a.Date, sum(b.Var1) as sum_var1
from table1 a
left outer join table1 b
on a.ID = b.ID
and months_between(a.date,b.date) <0
and months_between(a.date,b.date) > -3
```

Is there any way to do this in Pandas?

Comment: Have a look at this ;) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14646336/pandas-grouping-intra-day-timeseries-by-date

Comment: I hope this will be helpful. [https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/comparison_with_sql.html](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/comparison_with_sql.html)

Comment: Are you looking to use pandas to do the querying specifically?  or could you query then store the results in a dataframe?  or are you trying to do something equatable to what you described above using a dataframe you already have?

Comment: I am trying to do the same as shown , but entirely in pandas df if possible.

Comment: So you are trying to actually query a database using pandas?  why not just use pandas.read_sql?  I think I may still be misunderstanding you.

Comment: The data is in a data frame. I'm trying to find out how to replicate the SQL functionality in pandas

Comment: To create another dataframe with that summarization

Comment: Ah okay I understand now

Answer (score 2):

It seems you need `GroupBy` + `rolling`. Implementing the logic in precisely the same way it is written in SQL is likely to be expensive as it will involve repeated loops. Let's take an example dataframe:

```
        Date  ID  Var1
0 2015-01-01   1     0
1 2015-02-01   1     1
2 2015-03-01   1     2
3 2015-04-01   1     3
4 2015-05-01   1     4
5 2015-01-01   2     5
6 2015-02-01   2     6
7 2015-03-01   2     7
8 2015-04-01   2     8
9 2015-05-01   2     9
```

You can add a column which, by group, looks back and sums a variable over a fixed period. First define a function utilizing [`pd.Series.rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.Series.rolling.html):

```
def lookbacker(x):
    """Sum over past 70 days"""
    return x.rolling('70D').sum().astype(int)
```

Then apply it on a `GroupBy` object and extract values for assignment:

```
df['Lookback_Sum'] = df.set_index('Date').groupby('ID')['Var1'].apply(lookbacker).values

print(df)

        Date  ID  Var1  Lookback_Sum
0 2015-01-01   1     0             0
1 2015-02-01   1     1             1
2 2015-03-01   1     2             3
3 2015-04-01   1     3             6
4 2015-05-01   1     4             9
5 2015-01-01   2     5             5
6 2015-02-01   2     6            11
7 2015-03-01   2     7            18
8 2015-04-01   2     8            21
9 2015-05-01   2     9            24
```

It appears `pd.Series.rolling` does *not* work with months, e.g. using `'2M'` (2 months) instead of `'70D'` (70 days) gives `ValueError: <2 * MonthEnds> is a non-fixed frequency`. This makes sense since a "month" is ambiguous given months have different numbers of days.

Another point worth mentioning is you *can* use `GroupBy` + `rolling` directly and possibly more efficiently by bypassing `apply`, but this requires ensuring your index is monotic. For example, via `sort_index`:

```
df['Lookback_Sum'] = df.set_index('Date').sort_index()\
                       .groupby('ID')['Var1'].rolling('70D').sum()\
                       .astype(int).values
```

Comment: So you're stuck writing a custom rolling function if it truly needs to be calendar months? Seems unfortunate since `pd.offsets.DateOffset(months=3)` knows exactly what a calendar month is.

Comment: @ALollz, You seem to imply that there's *one and only one* way to "add *n* months". That simply isn't true. E.g. `2018-01-31 + 1m = 2018-02-28` (i.e. last day of month to last day of month), but `2018-02-28 + 1m = 2018-03-28` (i.e. use day instead of "last day of month" logic). This may make *perfect* sense to you, but it's just *one* way of counting dates.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `pandas.DataFrame.rolling()` supports rolling-window aggregation by some number of months; currently, you must specify a fixed number of days, or other fixed-length time period.

But as @jpp mentioned, you can use python loops to perform rolling aggregation over a window size specified in calendar months, where the number of days in each window will vary, depending on what part of the calendar you're rolling over.

The following approach builds on [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47199274) as well as @jpp's:

```
# Build some example data:
# 3 unique IDs, each with 365 samples, one sample per day throughout 2015
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': pd.date_range('2015-01-01', '2015-12-31', freq='D'),
                   'Var1': list(range(365))})
df = pd.concat([df] * 3)
df['ID'] = [1]*365 + [2]*365 + [3]*365
df.head()
        Date  Var1  ID
0 2015-01-01     0   1
1 2015-01-02     1   1
2 2015-01-03     2   1
3 2015-01-04     3   1
4 2015-01-05     4   1

# Define a lookback function that mimics rolling aggregation,
# but uses DateOffset() slicing, rather than a window of fixed size.
# Use .count() here as a sanity check; you will need .sum()
def lookbacker(ser): 
    return pd.Series([ser.loc[d - pd.offsets.DateOffset(months=3):d].count() 
                      for d in ser.index])

# By default, groupby.agg output is sorted by key. So make sure to 
# sort df by (ID, Date) before inserting the flattened groupby result 
# into a new column
df.sort_values(['ID', 'Date'], inplace=True)
df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
df['window_size'] = df.groupby('ID')['Var1'].apply(lookbacker).values

# Manually check the resulting window sizes
df.head()
            Var1  ID  window_size
Date                             
2015-01-01     0   1            1
2015-01-02     1   1            2
2015-01-03     2   1            3
2015-01-04     3   1            4
2015-01-05     4   1            5

df.tail()
            Var1  ID  window_size
Date                             
2015-12-27   360   3           92
2015-12-28   361   3           92
2015-12-29   362   3           92
2015-12-30   363   3           92
2015-12-31   364   3           93

df[df.ID == 1].loc['2015-05-25':'2015-06-05']
            Var1  ID  window_size
Date                             
2015-05-25   144   1           90
2015-05-26   145   1           90
2015-05-27   146   1           90
2015-05-28   147   1           90
2015-05-29   148   1           91
2015-05-30   149   1           92
2015-05-31   150   1           93
2015-06-01   151   1           93
2015-06-02   152   1           93
2015-06-03   153   1           93
2015-06-04   154   1           93
2015-06-05   155   1           93
```

The last column gives the lookback window size in days, looking back from that date, including both the start and end dates.

Looking "3 months" before `2016-05-31` would land you at `2015-02-31`, but February has only 28 days in 2015. As you can see in the sequence `90, 91, 92, 93` in the above sanity check, This `DateOffset` approach maps the last four days in May to the last day in February:

```
pd.to_datetime('2015-05-31') - pd.offsets.DateOffset(months=3)
Timestamp('2015-02-28 00:00:00')

pd.to_datetime('2015-05-30') - pd.offsets.DateOffset(months=3)
 Timestamp('2015-02-28 00:00:00')

pd.to_datetime('2015-05-29') - pd.offsets.DateOffset(months=3)
Timestamp('2015-02-28 00:00:00')

pd.to_datetime('2015-05-28') - pd.offsets.DateOffset(months=3)
Timestamp('2015-02-28 00:00:00')
```

I don't know if this matches SQL's behaviour, but in any case, you'll want to test this and decide if this makes sense in your case.

Answer (score 0):

you could use lambda to achieve it.

```
table1['sum_var1'] = table1.apply(lambda row: findSum(row), axis=1)
```

and we should write an equivalent method for months_between

the complete example is

```
from datetime import datetime
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd

def months_between(date1, date2):
    if date1.day == date2.day:
        return (date1.year - date2.year) * 12 + date1.month - date2.month
    # if both are last days
    if date1.month != (date1 + dt.timedelta(days=1)).month :
        if date2.month != (date2 + dt.timedelta(days=1)).month :
            return date1.month - date2.month
    return (date1 - date2).days / 31

def findSum(cRow):
    table1['month_diff'] = table1['Date'].apply(months_between, date2=cRow['Date'])
    filtered_table = table1[(table1["month_diff"] < 0) & (table1["month_diff"] > -3) & (table1['ID'] == cRow['ID'])]
    if filtered_table.empty:
        return 0
    return filtered_table['Var1'].sum()


table1 = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['ID', 'Date', 'Var1'])
table1.loc[len(table1)] = [1, datetime.strptime('2015-01-01','%Y-%m-%d'), 0]
table1.loc[len(table1)] = [1, datetime.strptime('2015-02-01','%Y-%m-%d'), 1]
table1.loc[len(table1)] = [1, datetime.strptime('2015-03-01','%Y-%m-%d'), 2]
table1.loc[len(table1)] = [1, datetime.strptime('2015-04-01','%Y-%m-%d'), 3]
table1.loc[len(table1)] = [1, datetime.strptime('2015-05-01','%Y-%m-%d'), 4]

table1.loc[len(table1)] = [2, datetime.strptime('2015-01-01','%Y-%m-%d'), 5]
table1.loc[len(table1)] = [2, datetime.strptime('2015-02-01','%Y-%m-%d'), 6]
table1.loc[len(table1)] = [2, datetime.strptime('2015-03-01','%Y-%m-%d'), 7]
table1.loc[len(table1)] = [2, datetime.strptime('2015-04-01','%Y-%m-%d'), 8]
table1.loc[len(table1)] = [2, datetime.strptime('2015-05-01','%Y-%m-%d'), 9]

table1['sum_var1'] = table1.apply(lambda row: findSum(row), axis=1)
table1.drop(columns=['month_diff'], inplace=True)
print(table1)
```